# Why isn't IIS serving my static CSS / JS files?

Tags: iis, asp.net-mvc, static-files, http-status-code-404

I added an ASP.NET MVC3 site to ISS (which was working fine in the debugger). When viewing the site in a browser, everything appeared to be working fine except that all of the CSS and JS files were returning a 404.

Here is the site in IIS Manager:

[image]

**Other details:**

- OS: Windows Vista Home Premium 32-bit (with SP2)
- IIS: 7.0.6000.16386
- Visual Studio 2010 Express with SP1

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It sounds like a permissions error. Did you remember to add the IIS User `IIS_IUSRS` to the list of users that can access the files?

Comment: Woops... I gave `IIS_IUSRS` full access to the folder and it's working now.

Comment: How to set it up in IIS Express? and how come there is no IIS_IUSRS in my computer?

Comment: Like @Blaise I'd like to know how to manage IIS users with IIS Express.